# editorconfig - correct IDE suggestion for PascalCase method naming

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editorconfig

In a `.editorconfig` file, I want to add a rule defining that a **method** is written in PascalCase.

My expectation now is:

```cs
// Entered function name
public void pascalcasefunction() { }

// Expected IDE suggestion:
public void PascalCaseFunction() { }

// Actual IDE suggestion:
public void Pascalcasefunction() { }
```

[IDE suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYmUQ.png)

Therefore I have added the default `.editorconfig` file provided by Microsoft and appended the following rule:

```
# SYMBOL GROUPS - Defining the 'method_symbols' symbol group.
dotnet_naming_symbols.method_symbols.applicable_kinds           = method
dotnet_naming_symbols.method_symbols.applicable_accessibilities = *

# NAMING STYLE - Defining the `method_name_pascal_case` naming style.
dotnet_naming_style.method_name_pascal_case.capitalization      = pascal_case

# CODING RULE - Defining the `convention_method_name_rule` naming rule.
dotnet_naming_rule.convention_method_name_rule.symbols          = method_symbols
dotnet_naming_rule.convention_method_name_rule.style            = method_name_pascal_case
dotnet_naming_rule.convention_method_name_rule.severity         = error
```

PascalCase not only describes to begin with upper case characters. Is there a possibility in which the IDE detects PascalCase violation based on the words that are used in a string?

Comment: I'm not sure how the IDE would detect that `Pascalcasefunction` is wrong, but `PascalCaseFunction` is right. It would need to be using a dictionary, but code often uses domain-specific terms quite heavily, so the dictionary would need to be heavily customised by you, and constantly maintained

Comment: I also don't have any idea on how the IDE could detect it. I am wondering why it is possible to have the option for defining PascalCase.

Due to the rules section for editorconfig it is possible to define `pascal_case`, `camel_case`, `first_word_upper`, `all_upper` and `all_lower`.
So what would be the difference between pascal and first upper for example?

Source: [MSDoc Codestyle rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules)

Comment: If the original is in, say, snake case (e.g., `pascal_case_function`), the IDE can know where the words start and therefore can suggest `PascalCaseFunction` instead (that's not to say it *will*, just that it *can*). Otherwise, it's a guessing game. As far as "why it is possible"; you can define whatever you want and it will do the best it can to fulfill your wishes. The IDE does have access to dictionaries, and is able to parse some words. For instance, I can recall having to fix methods with names like `GetXMLfromdb` to `GetXmlFromDb` because of IDE errors.

Comment: If you use StyleCop to verify your code, the above probably works, because it _does_ have a dictionary. It will also suggest to correct typos in names.

Comment: If you want to use `.editorconfig` to change the method naming constraint to a big camel case, it is not feasible through my research. There is no such rule in the existing rules.